# UTF8, UTF16 encoding string search

Tags: debuggers, x64dbg

I want to search for a string written in Georgian from within x64dbg. It shows me spaces except them..

P.S I found this [github repository](https://github.com/x64dbg/strmatch) but, I don't know how to install the plugin in the debugger... it seems to be a different kind of plugin.. please help, I need it like air.. thanks!

Comment: I think that plugin doesn't do what you want. It is used rather for string comparison while tracing. Basically, you assign each string some numeric value and then you can compare it as you would compare two numbers. However, if it is what you want, let me know and I'll show you how to install it.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could provide an example executable that show this replacing the text with spaces...

Comment: Alternatively, the string can be searched in hex viewer, for example HxD.